# Using comparable to sort array

Tags: java, arrays, comparable

I am writing a program where a user adds a set of Integers, and I have to use a comparable to sort the array. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
public class Set<E extends Comparable<E>> {

String s;
String name;
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
private E[] theData;
private int size = 0;
private int capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Set() {
    theData = (E[]) new Comparable[capacity];
}

public Set(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void add(E item) {

    if (size == capacity) {
            reallocate();
        }

        if(size == 0){
            theData[0] = item;
            size++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int result = item.compareTo(theData[i]);

            if (result < 0){
                theData[i+1] = theData[i];
                theData[i] = item;
                size++;
            }

            if (result > 0){
                theData[i+1] = item;

            }
        }




}

public E get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return theData[index];
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

private void reallocate() {
    capacity = 2 * capacity;
    theData = Arrays.copyOf(theData, capacity);
}

}
```

My idea with the add method is to compare each added item (the number being added to a set). If the item is less than the value of theData[i], shift theData[i] forward a spot into theData[i+1], and place the item in theData[i].

If it is greater than the value in theData[i], place the item in i+1 and leave the lower value in element i.

I've tried re-writing my loops, using a nested loop to iterate through the rest of the elements, but something must be off in my logic because I'm not getting any better results.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `Arrays.sort`? instead?

Comment: I've been directed not to, but also when I tried it out to see how much easier it would be, I got an error: java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)

Comment: What is going wrong with this? What are you asking, specifically?

Comment: Which from my understanding has something to do with using Arrays.sort with an object array (which I have to use)?

Comment: look at this link http://www.journaldev.com/780/java-comparable-and-comparator-example-to-sort-objects,, http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt, whenever I add items to a Set<Integer>, and attempt to display the contents of the Set, I get an IndexOutofBoundsException: 10.

Comment: So what do you do when you already have filled your array with 10 elements, and you're going to add element 11? I don't see anything in your code that increases the size of your array `theData` so logically you're going to run out of space when you want to add the elements beyond the 10th.

Comment: I wrote the reallocate() method for that purpose, I just forgot to call it with an if statement in my add method. I added that above. But I still get the IndexOutofBounds error somehow.

Comment: So, what does your reallocate method do? I don't see any code that increases the size of `theData`. You only change the value of the `int` field `capacity` but you don't really change the capacity of `theData`.

Comment: Doesn't the line "theData = Arrays.copyOf(theData, capacity);" make a copy of the original array with the new capacity?

Comment: Do you mean the line that you commented out ? `// theData = Arrays.copyOf(theData, capacity);`

Comment: hey rewriting loops wont work.. 'cuz each time size in add method is initialized to "0", so your for loop is not working, no comparison is done and hence no insertion is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time "size" in add method is initialized to "0", so your for loop is not working, no comparison is done.
try using `"for(int i=0; i<theData.length; i++)"` instead.
but after that you may face NullPointerException coz you have initialised initial capacity to 10.
writing a separate compare method may work..

```
public int compare(E o1, E o2) {
       return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```